# about torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss parameter shape

Tags: loss, pytorch

i'm learning pytorch, and taking the anpr project,which is based tensorflow
(https://github.com/matthewearl/deep-anpr,
http://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/)
as a exercise, transplant it to pytorch platform.

there is a problem,i'm using nn.CrossEntropyLoss() as loss function:

```
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

the output.data of model is:

```
  - 1.00000e-02 *
   - 2.5552 2.7582 2.5368 ... 5.6184 1.2288 -0.0076
   - 0.7033 1.3167 -1.0966 ... 4.7249 1.3217 1.8367
   - 0.7592 1.4777 1.8095 ... 0.8733 1.2417 1.1521
   - 0.1040 -0.7054 -3.4862 ... 4.7703 2.9595 1.4263 
   - [torch.FloatTensor of size 4x253]
```

and targets.data is:

```
 - 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0
 - 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0
 - 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0
 - 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0
 - [torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x253]
```

when i call:

```
loss=criterion(output,targets)
```

error occured,information is:

```
TypeError: FloatClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, torch.FloatTensor, **torch.DoubleTensor**, torch.FloatTensor, bool, NoneType, torch.FloatTensor), but expected (int state, torch.FloatTensor input, **torch.LongTensor** target, torch.FloatTensor output, bool sizeAverage, [torch.FloatTensor weights or None], torch.FloatTensor total_weight)

'expected torch.LongTensor'......'got torch.DoubleTensor',but if i convert the targets into LongTensor:
torch.LongTensor(numpy.array(targets.data.numpy(),numpy.long))
```

call loss=criterion(output,targets), the error is:

```
RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /data/users/soumith/miniconda2/conda-bld/pytorch-0.1.10_1488752595704/work/torch/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:20
```

my last exercise is mnist, a example from pytorch,i made a bit modification,batch_size is 4,the loss function:

```
loss = F.nll_loss(outputs, labels)
```

outputs.data:

```
 - -2.3220 -2.1229 -2.3395 -2.3391 -2.5270 -2.3269 -2.1055 -2.2321 -2.4943 -2.2996

   -2.3653 -2.2034 -2.4437 -2.2708 -2.5114 -2.3286 -2.1921 -2.1771 -2.3343 -2.2533

   -2.2809 -2.2119 -2.3872 -2.2190 -2.4610 -2.2946 -2.2053 -2.3192 -2.3674 -2.3100

   -2.3715 -2.1455 -2.4199 -2.4177 -2.4565 -2.2812 -2.2467 -2.1144 -2.3321 -2.3009

   [torch.FloatTensor of size 4x10]
```

labels.data:

```
 - 8 
 - 6 
 - 0 
 - 1 
 - [torch.LongTensor of size 4]
```

the labels, for a input image,must be a single element, in upper example, there is 253 numbers, and in 'mnist',there is only one number, the shape of outputs is difference from labels.

i review the tensorflow manual, tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits,
'Logits and labels must have the sameshape [batch_size, num_classes] and the same dtype (either float32 or float64).'

does pytorch support the same function in tensorflow?

many thks

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the targets that you have to a categorical representation.
In the example that you provide, you would have 1 0 0 0.. 0 if the class is 0, 0 1 0 0 ... if the class is 1, 0 0 1 0 0 0... if the class is 2 etc.
One quick way that I can think of is first convert the target Tensor to a numpy array, then convert it from one hot to a categorical array, and convert it back to a pytorch Tensor. Something like this:

```
targetnp=targets.numpy()
idxs=np.where(targetnp>0)[1]
new_targets=torch.LongTensor(idxs)
loss=criterion(output,new_targets)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CrossEntropyLoss` is equivalent to `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. The input to `CrossEntropyLoss`  is a categorical vector of shape [batch_size]. Use `.view()` to change the tensor shapes.

`labels = labels.view(-1)
output = output.view(labels.size(0), -1)
loss = criterion(output, loss)`

calling `.view(x, y, -1)` causes the tensor to use the remaining datapoints to fill the `-1` dimension and will cause an error if there is not enough to make a full dimension

`labels.size(0)` gives the size of the 0th dimension of the `label` tensor

**Additional**

to convert between tensor types you can call the type on the tensor, for example 'labels = labels.long()`

**Second Additional**

If you unpack the data from a variable like so `output.data` then you will lose the gradients for that output and be unable to backprop when the time comes